# Looking for clarification around Task.WhenAll and await in async MVC web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I've been investigating how to incorporate asynchronous methods into my MVC controllers, specifically to leverage the potential of parallel execution.

I found [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) particularly helpful. However there's one concept I'd appreciate clarification on. The article I linked above uses the following code to execute a series of I/O-bound methods in parallel:

```
var widgetTask = widgetService.GetWidgetsAsync();
var prodTask = prodService.GetProductsAsync();
var gizmoTask = gizmoService.GetGizmosAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(widgetTask, prodTask, gizmoTask);

var pwgVM = new ProdGizWidgetVM(
   widgetTask.Result,
   prodTask.Result,
   gizmoTask.Result
   );
```

What I'd like to know is how this differs from the following code:

```
var widgetTask = widgetService.GetWidgetsAsync();
var prodTask = prodService.GetProductsAsync();
var gizmoTask = gizmoService.GetGizmosAsync();

var pwgVM = new ProdGizWidgetVM(
   await widgetTask,
   await prodTask,
   await gizmoTask
   );
```

According to my understanding these two code blocks are equivalent. Is that correct? If not it'd be great if someone could explain the difference and suggest which is preferable in my case.

Comment: The first snippet waits for *all* tasks to complete. The second, waits for them sequentially and isn't the easiest code to maintain. Imagine, eg trying to add a breakpoint after all task finish, in order to inspect their results. Trivial in #1, impossible in #2.

Comment: Right, I see your point about debugging. That's an important point I hadn't considered. But for completeness of my understanding, am I right in saying that in #2 the methods are still executed in parallel? In that case it wouldn't matter that the results are awaited sequentially because I can only continue once all are complete anyway.

Comment: `await` doesn't affect execution. The tasks started executing when you called the asynchronous method. `await` only affects asynchronous *awaiting*. In that sense only, both snippets are equivalent. It probably still matters though, because the compiler has to generate a 3-step state machine for awaiting instead of a 1-step state machine. The compiler may be smart enough to *optimize* the second snippet and replace it with `await Task.WhenAll` but I doubt it

Answer (score 0):

**1 will execute all 3 Tasks in parallel but not necessarily in order**

`Task.WhenAll` completes, when all tasks inside have completed. `widgetTask` will be executed to its first await, then while waiting asynchronous for the io-bound work, `prodTask` will be executed to its first await and while still waiting for the first 2 Tasks to complete, `gizmoTask` will be executed to its first await. Then after all 3 have finished executing the io-bound work in parallel, they will run to completion. After this, `Task.WhenAll` will also report completion.

**2 will execute all 3 Tasks in parallel and in the given order**

`widgetTask` will start, then `prodTask` will start and then `gizmoTask`. The you start awaiting `widgetTask`. When it has completed, it will return and the non io-bound code that is inside this task will run. After it has finished, `prodTask` will be awaited. As the io-bound work of it happened asynchronous it might already be completed, so this will be quite fast. After the io-bound work completed, to code after the await inside of `prodTask` will be called. Same for `gizmoTask`

So normally you want version 1 and not version 2 as long as you do not care about the order in which the code after the await inside your task is executed.

Comment: All three tasks start when called.   Waiting on all 3 in a `Task.WaitAll` or individually doesn't change that.  Now if the `awaits` where before the calls to `GetWidgetsAsync` then you would be correct, but that is not the case.

Comment: Thank you. As I suspected, by understanding of async and await was incomplete. This explains perfectly.

Comment: @getsetcode This answer is wrong.  You should listen to what Panagiotis put in his comments instead.

Comment: OK, I've 'unaccepted' the answer and would appreciate if someone could add a definitive answer :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I read something wrong. I corrected my answer, now it should be sufficent.